# Hedera Token Service/NFT - Is there a limit to how many NFT tokens can be created?

Tags: nft, hedera-hashgraph

I have a question about minting NFTs on Hedera.

Is there a limit to the number of NFTs that can be created?

For example, if I want to create 300,000 NFTs on one token ID. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is a limit but it's very high. The max total supply of a native Hedera token is stored in `LONG` variable so the limit is 2<sup>64</sup> so 300,000 NFT is %100 possible.